# continue after exec command in t-sql

Tags: t-sql

With-in t-sql I want to execute one proceduere and go for next excuatable statment immidiatly i.e. do not wait to complete that particular command line.
e.g.

`Statment1`

`Statment2`

`exec dbtemp..CustomeProc1`

`Statement3`

In above example after start processing of 
`exec dbtemp..CustomeProc1`
programe should not wait to complete the action and go for

`Statement3`

Answer (score 0):

T-SQL isn’t going to work because these needs to run asynchronously and not synchronously (all at the same time not one after the other) and T-SQL doesn’t have that option.

Using Powershell you can achieve it -

```
$Server= "(local)\sql2016cs" ;
$DBName = "Test" ; 
$Commands = @()
$Commands += @()
$Commands += "EXEC dbtemp..CustomeProc1"
$Commands += @()  
foreach ($sql in $Commands ) {  
$cmdstr =@"`Add-Type -AssemblyName"Microsoft.SqlServer.Smo,Version=$(13).0.0.0,Culture=neutral,PublicKeyToken=89845dcd8080cc91"
`[System.Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName("Microsoft.SqlServer.Smo")
`$SqlConn = New-Object Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Smo.Server ("$Server")
`$SqlConn.Databases["$DBName"].ExecuteNonQuery("$sql")
"@
$cmd = [ScriptBlock]::Create($cmdstr)
Start-Job -ScriptBlock $cmd
}
```